# Zoom dependency of GLAD alerts raster layers visualization in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-mosaic

Please see the simple EE code below, which basically displays 2 different layers of information, selected and masked from the GLAD alerts image collection.

```
var all_alerts  = ee.ImageCollection('projects/glad/alert/UpdResult');
var country     = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CG'));
var alerts_2021 = all_alerts.select('alertDate21','conf21').mosaic().clip(country);
var alertMasked = alerts_2021.mask(alerts_2021.gt(0));
var viz = {palette: ['FFFF00', '00FF00']};

Map.centerObject(country, 9);
Map.addLayer(alertMasked.select('alertDate21'), viz, 'alertDOY', true);

var alerts_conf = all_alerts.select('conf21').mosaic().clip(country);
var alertMasked2 = alerts_conf.mask(alerts_conf.gt(0));
Map.addLayer(alertMasked2, {palette:['red']}, 'alert',true);
```

Despite the layers are masked based on different data, their spatial extent should be the same.
However, at small scale *alertDOY* (the yellow-green palette one) looks much larger than *alert* (the red one). This is evident if one toggles on-off the layers).
But after zooming in, it is clear that the 2 layers coincide.
How can this been fixed/explained?